# php slim array wrong response

Tags: php, api, slim

Hi guys i'm trying to get json response from server, but my server send wrong array response, what i do wrong, why i get this wring response:

```
{
"error": false,
"status": 200,
"news": {
    "0": {
        "id": 30
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 28
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 32
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 31
    }
}
}
```

This is my php code:

```
 <?
 require_once '../include/DBHandler.php';
 require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
 \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
 $app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/main', function() {
$response = array();
    $db  = new DBHandler();
    $result = $db->getMainNews();
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["status"] = 200;
    $response["news"] = array();
    while($new = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $new["id"];
        array_push($response["news"], $tmp);
    }

}
);  
 $app->run();
```

Comment: `why i get this wring response` - and what is the **right** response?

Comment: right array like this: [news: {id: 1}

Comment: This is correct json syntax I guess. Check with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Please edit your question for right response.

Comment: You're overwriting the $tmp array each time you go through the while loop, is that what you want to do? Once the array is complete use json_encode()

Comment: I think you want `{news:[{id:1},{id:2}]}`

Comment: @user1784961 gview's answer should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to manually setup a response when what you should be doing is using the embedded response object.

See examples in the [slim manual](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Response-Overview):

For example:

```
$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$return = array();
$db  = new DBHandler();
$result = $db->getMainNews();

$return["news"] = array();
while($new = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $new["id"];
    array_push($return["news"], $tmp);
}
$app->response->body(json_encode($return));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
$response = array();
$db  = new DBHandler();
$result = $db->getMainNews();
//$response["error"] = false;
//$response["status"] = 200;
$response["news"] = array();
while($new = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $new["id"];
    array_push($response["news"], $tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the same error now. I debugged minutely and figured out the culprit is the line

```
require_once '../include/DBHandler.php';
```

For some reason, slim is adding an extra '{' or '}' to the json response when this line is added. I am not able to work on Slim anymore since you would need atleast one such statement to use other php class files